# How can we say that a clustering quality measure is good?

Tags: machine-learning, cluster-analysis, measurement

There are few well known measures like silhouette width (SW), the Davies- Bouldin index (DB), the Calinski-Harabasz  index (CH), and the Dunn index .
How can we say that a clustering quality measure is good?
Is there some kind of metric for the clustering quality measure to be good?

Also ,

> "algorithms that produce clusters with high Dunn index are more desirable" -Wikipedia
>
> "Objects with a high silhouette value are considered well clustered" -Wikipedia
>
> "clustering algorithm that produces a collection of clusters with the smallest Davies–Bouldin index is considered the best algorithm"   -Wikipedia

How  high or low these values should be ?Is there a metric number ?

Can any one provide me a small example using a clustering quality measure  on a dataset or IRIS dataset to say that the particular clustering quality measure is good?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a simple starting point  would be:

> "Are the elements within a cluster alike and are they different from
>   elements in a different cluster".

There are obviously a variety of metrics to quantify similarity vs difference - as well as considerations like density vs distance.

The Stanford NLP project has a useful reference that is approachable: http://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/html/htmledition/evaluation-of-clustering-1.html

Comment: I mean How can you say that the particular clustering quality measure [CQM] silhouette width / Davies- Bouldin index / Calinski-Harabasz index / Dunn index is  a better than the rest?